How do I stream a large BZ2 data file using Python requests stream=True/iter_content()?
I have a large data file at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageview_complete/monthly/2024/2024-07/pageviews-202407-user.bz2 (3.3 GB).
I'm trying to stream its contents and process it line by line, by using requests stream=True and iter_content().
The logic works fine, and I can process data for about 15-20 minutes before I get:
<SNIP>
urllib3.exceptions.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(123551405 bytes read, 3479106984 more expected)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

<SNIP>
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(123551405 bytes read, 3479106984 more expected)', IncompleteRead(123551405 bytes read, 3479106984 more expected))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

<SNIP>
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(123551405 bytes read, 3479106984 more expected)', IncompleteRead(123551405 bytes read, 3479106984 more expected))

Here's my code:
@contextmanager
def get_pageview_response():
  url = get_pageview_url()
  with requests.get(url,
                    stream=True,
                    headers={
                        'User-Agent': WP1_USER_AGENT,
                        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
                    },
                    timeout=120) as r:
    
    r.raise_for_status()
    yield r


def raw_pageviews(decode=False):

  def as_bytes():
    with get_pageview_response() as r:
      decompressor = BZ2Decompressor()
      trailing = b''
      # Read data in 128 MB chunks
      for http_chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128 * 1024 * 1024):
        data = decompressor.decompress(http_chunk)
        lines = [line for line in data.split(b'\n') if line]
        if not lines:
          continue

        # Reunite incomplete lines
        yield trailing + lines[0]
        yield from lines[1:-1]
        trailing = lines[-1]

      # Nothing left, yield the last line
      yield trailing

  if decode:
    for line in as_bytes():
      yield line.decode('utf-8')
  else:
    yield from as_bytes()

def pageview_components():
  for line in raw_pageviews():
    pass  # Processing logic goes here

Based on reading the error message, my current guess is that after 15-20 minutes, my data processing (which includes I/O operations to write to a MariaDB instance) is "falling behind" the HTTP streaming. I imagine that the HTTP socket goes "idle" and the server closes the connection.
Does that sound right? Does it have anything to do with my BZ2 decompression step?
I've tried increasing the HTTP chunk size to 128 MB (from 16 MB) to allow for more "buffer", but that doesn't seem to help.

Why not write the bz2 dump to disk, then import the bz2 dump into your SQL database? That would likely avoid this timeout issue by making the download much faster.

I would expect that if Wikipedia has an idle timeout, then increasing the chunk size would make timeouts worse, as it means that the connection would go longer without making a read.

I suppose I will have to download the entire file to disk if I can't figure this out!

Can you post full(-er) stacktrace, at least the part inside requests? I suspect it tries to read the whole chunk_size, but the last chunk is smaller then requested. Also, setting chunk_size to None could help in this case

You can see from the stack trace that it only read ~123 MB of the 3.3 GB. If I set chunk_size to None, the iterator never yields (which I assume means it's trying to download the whole file).
